# ¿como unir dos consultas select en php?

Tags: php, mysql

hola tengo un problema relativamente fácil pero ya me confundi en como estructurar la consulta quiero hacer una consulta para aplicar un `sum` con su respectivo `where` y otra para simplemente traerme datos de la BD con su respectivo `where` se podría hacer todo en una misma consulta pero tengo diferentes condiciones en ambas consultas por eso tiene que ser por separado

lo que intento es mostrar los datos de una tabla de la base de datos en una tabla html y mostrar un `total` del `campo monto total`

mis datos los obtengo correctamente solo me falta saber generar la consulta que me trae la suma y colocarlo en la tabla html

```
<?php
$factura=$_POST['factura'];
$empresa=$_POST['empresa'];

$con=mysqli_connect(
  "localhost",
  "root","",
  "controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$query="SELECT vehiculo, fecha_carga, rendimiento_kilometro, 
  rendimiento_real, ticket, factura, costo_total, empresa
  FROM carga_combustible
  WHERE factura='$factura' AND empresa='$empresa'
  ORDER BY fecha_carga DESC
";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());

$suma="SELECT SUM(costo_total) AS monto
  FROM carga_combustible
  WHERE factura ='$factura'
";
$resultado=mysqli_query($con, $suma) or die (mysqli_error());

echo "<table class='table table-hover table-sm table-bordered table-condensed' id='exportar'>
<thead class='thead-dark text-center'>

<tr>
<th colspan='8' scope='rowgroup' class='bg-info text-center'><h3>Reporte de Consumos de Gasolina </h3></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Vehículo</th>
<th>Fecha de Carga</th>
<th>Rendimiento x km</th>
<th>Rendiemiento Real</th>
<th>Ticket</th>
<th>Factura</th>
<th>Monto Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

$total=0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $totalmonto=$total+$row[0];
  $empresa=$row[7];
  echo "<tbody class='text-center'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</tbody>";

}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th colspan='8' scope='rowgroup' class='bg-info text-center'></th>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo"<th colspan='5'>$empresa</th>";
echo "<td colspan='1'>TOTAL:</td>";
echo "<td colspan='1'>$totalmonto</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
mysqli_query( $con, $query ) or die ("Problemas al llamar tabla".mysqli_error());
mysqli_close( $con );
```

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si agregas una muestra de los datos de salida que esperas obtener

Comment: listo ya edite mi pregunta si te fijas en mi código tengo dos consultas en una obtengo mis datos y en la otra obtengo la suma del monto total pero al pasar el valor de la segunda consulta que es un 0 puesto que es el primer lugar de dicha consulta, me toma el valor de la primera consulta el 0 que vendría siendo el campo vehículo cuando debería de ser monto, no se si me entiendas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respecto a tu pregunta "se podría hacer todo en una misma consulta" la respuesta es si, seria de esta forma

```
SELECT f.vehiculo, f.fecha_carga, f.rendimiento_kilometro, f.rendimiento_real,f.ticket, f.factura, f.costo_total, f.empresa
FROM (
    SELECT vehiculo, fecha_carga, rendimiento_kilometro, rendimiento_real, ticket, factura, costo_total, empresa
         FROM carga_combustible
         WHERE factura = '1'
           AND empresa = '1'

    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TOTALES', max(fecha_carga), '', '', '', '', SUM(costo_total), empresa
         FROM carga_combustible
         WHERE factura ='1' 
           AND empresa='1'
     ) AS f ORDER BY f.fecha_carga DESC
```

Pero con esto el total estaria dentro del loop al final.

Comment: lo intente como me indicas pero no dio resultado de igual manera muchas gracias por tu sugerencia , ya lo resolví

Comment: cual es el resultado que buscabas?

Comment: buscaba algo como una subquery y si de hecho lo intente con union pero no era la adecuada para lo que necesitaba sino un inner join asi:

Comment: select vehiculo,fecha_carga,rendimiento_kilometro,rendimiento_real,ticket,T.factura,costo_total,empresa,A.monto
from carga_combustible T
INNER JOIN (
select sum(costo_total) as monto,factura
from carga_combustible 
where factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn' 
GROUP BY factura
) A ON A.factura=T.factura
where T.factura ='CD31922' and empresa='csn'
order by fecha_carga desc